# Creating a uniqueidentifer column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, guid, uniqueidentifier

I'm using SQLServer for a project, and have uuids in my models. The appropriate column type for them would be UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, but I'm not sure how I would do that in Rails. Generally, if I'm just testing, I could use strings. That isn't the case here though.

I doubt the migration file is as simple as `t.unique_identifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following migration file would work.

```
class ChangeUniqueIdentifierInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'SQLServer'
      change_column :users, :payer_guid, :uniqueidentifier
    end
  end
end
```